# Extract "\field{abstract}{ . . . }" and "\keyw{ . . . }" fields from .bbl files for use in making wordclouds and other such datamining

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bbl

I have LaTeX files that are basically compendiums of the current research in several subfields in which I do research. I would like to be able to take the .bbl for those files and extract keywords (i.e., the "\keyw{ .  .  . }" field) and abstracts (i.e., the \field{abstract}{ .  .  .  }" and use those data for various nefarious purposes. Actually, my test case would be far from nefarious as it would be to create WordClouds from these data. Once successful at that I have a few more interesting ideas. However, the current stumbling block is the proverbial first step.

Any help? Much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to export the information? I assume it is not enough to extract the info with a `.tex` document? Do you want a bash script? An interface for your favourite programming language? There is https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibextract, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bib2xhtml, http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Text-BibTeX-0.80/lib/Text/BibTeX.pm, https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bibtex

Comment: Any news here? It is not entirely clear from your question what your requirements are.

Comment: last wordcloud I did used a .txt file in R. Not thinking of anything particularly complex for this one. Thanks for the comment and apologies for the slow response.

Answer (score 2):

There are packages for many programming languages that allow to parse `.bib` files.

- For Perl, there is `Text::BibTeX`: http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Text-BibTeX-0.80/
- For python there is `BibtexParser` https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/
- Haskell has its own package called `bibtex` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bibtex
- For R there are https://cran.r-project.org/package=bibtex and https://cran.r-project.org/package=RefManageR
- For Elisp I found https://github.com/joostkremers/parsebib
- Even for PHP there is something https://people.mmci.uni-saarland.de/~jilles/prj/phpBibLib/

There are also a few tools on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-util), for example [bib2xhtml](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bib2xhtml)  which converts `.bib` files to XHTML which might be easier to parse for you. You might also be able to cook up a solution with Biber directly, this all really depends on what exactly you are after.